# Value from Activity A to Activity B returning null

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, android-intent, uibutton

I am trying to get information from `Activity` B, into `Activity` A, the problem is that the value that i am getting is returning `null` for some reason.  My code see's how many times you click on the `Button` and returns the value into my first `Activity`, at least thats what it is suppose to do.  If sombody see's my mistake please tell me, i have class in 5 hours :\

```
returned.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Next.this, Hw3Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text", counted.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
/*Next is the current activity, Counted is the name of my text box*/
            }
        });
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
            }
```

This is the `Activity` i want the information transferred to.

```
Button change;
    TextView text;
    int number;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

        String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01");
        text.setText("You clicked the button " + s1 + " times.");

        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Next.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
/*this button is for going to the 2nd activity,not my problem currently*/
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you are doing wrong:

```
String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01");
```

i believe it should be:

```
String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
```

Comment: It wont let me accept the answr riht now but i will when it allows me too :)

Answer (score 2):

In the `Activity` where you want the info, there is an error.  You need to put `"text"` instead `"Textview01"`.

You can use the following with error control.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if( extras != null){
   String text = extras.getString("text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
`String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");`

Because You are sending string value tag as `"text"`.